# How to give on local to other pc access to your project in valet?

Tags: php, laravel

When I make a project in laravel I can give access with php artisan serve but if a make a normal project and make host with valet link the PHP artisan don't work because it's not a laravel project. How can i give access to local with valet ? For example i have project.dev and make `192.168.1.5:80` like in laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`valet park`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet#the-park-command) or [`valet link`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet#the-link-command) commands to be able to access your application locally.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say about valet share i want just on local not web i am new to this .how can i do on local just my pc to have access.

Comment: i say about valet link so if a go on my laptop who is connected on network can he access project.dev too ?

Comment: i want to share my project on my laptop . i don't like valet share.Hope is another method.

Answer (score 0):

For a local network, you will need to make sure your port is accessible if your're behind a firewall. You may need to setup port forwarding, as well, if NAT is involved.

Are you trying to make the project accessible to others on the internet? For this, you can use ngrok.

https://ngrok.com/

```
”I want to expose a local server behind a NAT or firewall to the internet.”
```

Comment: just on my local network how can i do that i have linux.